# QuickLookPreviewController share button mail subject line using UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I am using QuickLookPreviewController to view documents of different extensions within my application.

The built-in share button launches as UIActivityViewController.

I am looking to change the subject line when sharing using the email client.

The QLPreviewItem protocol only offers two properties: previewItemURL and previewItemTitle.

Is there any way to customise the QuickLookPreviewController so you can manually set the subject line when sharing using the built-in methods?

Comment: You could always subclass and override

Comment: @Erik - Do you know what methods specifically are responsible for the sharing functionality?